# redis slave won't sync with master

Tags: redis, replication

The redis slave won't sync with the master.

## Connectivity:

I can connect to the master when I issue

```
HOST_NAME=fakehost
redis-cli -h $HOST_NAME
```

and check the master status using a command like `INFO`, so connectivity is not an issue.

## Settings:

From the slave box, I issued

```
SLAVEOF $HOST_NAME 6379
```

And received an `OK`.

When I issue the `INFO` command on the slave, I get

```
# Replication
role:slave
master_host:<removed>
master_port:6379
master_link_status:down
master_last_io_seconds_ago:-1
master_sync_in_progress:0
master_link_down_since_seconds:1379450797
slave_priority:100
slave_read_only:1
connected_slaves:0
```

On the master box, I issue `info` and get

```
# Replication
role:master
connected_slaves:0
```

So obviously I'm not connected.

## Logs

```
[11225] 17 Sep 14:31:33.225 * Connecting to MASTER...
[11225] 17 Sep 14:31:33.226 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started
[11225] 17 Sep 14:31:33.226 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
[11225] 17 Sep 14:31:33.226 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
[11225] 17 Sep 14:31:33.227 # MASTER aborted replication with an error: ERR Unable to perform background save
```

## Tests

Test that dump.rdb is created on BGSAVE

```
BGSAVE
> OK
```

Test that dump.rdb is created on SAVE

```
SAVE
> OK
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the working directory set to and does the user have write privs?

Comment: yep, it has write priv.  it will write out the `dump.rdb` when I execute a save or start/stop.

Answer (score 13):

I encountered a similar situation today. It seems that for systems that use `sysctl`, you might have to do:

```
sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1
```

and restart the slave redis server. [This link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/redis-db/jACUC02FEtE/0ZZmk-CH8cIJ) might help.

Answer (score 10):

This issue little tricky,

the reason that the slave can't sync is in the master itself,

pay attention to the Log output : 
 **MASTER** aborted replication with an error: ERR Unable to perform **background save**

this is mean that the master can't do background saving due low memory reserve on the master machine,

to solve this issue I Restarted the master redis server , 
then all the slaves has been sync by themselves.

Comment: worked for me, I ran redis-cli shutdown save, which restarted redis while saving all keys and within seconds the slave was synced.

Answer (score 8):

For me, it was because I had `requirepass` set, but did not set a `masterauth` setting.

Answer (score 4):

I've met the same issue, and my reason is both of my servers do not use the same `redis version`. Let's check your version on both servers:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> info server
# Server
redis_version:3.2.8
```

Answer (score 3):

my default settings in redis.conf enabled requirepass,executing " masterauth [passwordOfMaster] "in slave's terminal before "SLAVEOF" will fix this issue.

Comment: To be 100% clear, the command one wants to issue is `config set masterauth [passwordOfMaster]`

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that protected mode was on when I tried to set this up using Redis 5.0.5. When I logged into the putative master on its eth0 interface (as opposed to loopback or UNIX socket) I got this message when I tried to run "INFO":

```
IP_ADDRESS_REDACTED:6379> info
DENIED Redis is running in protected mode because protected mode is
enabled, no bind address was specified, no authentication password
is requested to clients. In this mode connections are only accepted
from the loopback interface. If you want to connect from external
computers to Redis you may adopt one of the following solutions:
1) Just disable protected mode sending the command 'CONFIG SET 
protected-mode no' from the loopback interface by connecting to Redis
from the same host the server is running, however MAKE SURE Redis is
not publicly accessible from internet if you do so. Use CONFIG REWRITE 
to make this change permanent. 2) Alternatively you can just disable
the protected mode by editing the Redis configuration file, and
setting the protected mode option to 'no', and then restarting the
server. 3) If you started the server manually just for testing,
restart it with the '--protected-mode no' option. 4) Setup a bind
address or an authentication password. NOTE: You only need to do one
of the above things in order for the server to start accepting
connections from the outside.
```

I followed the instructions and the slave connected immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Possible fix:

Ensure both **masterauth** and **requirepass** values are the same on all servers (master/slaves).

Note: The masterauth value is basically asking for the authentication password into the master machine, for slaves trying to connect, thus not exactly relevant on the master machine itself, but relevent for slave machines when trying to sync with master. This is what the requirepass (the one you set in redis config on the Master machine) is for - i.e. the value you've set for requirepass on Master, is the same value you need to put in front of your masterauth parameter on the redis config slave machines. Best do the same too on Mater machine to avoid further confusion (although it won't be relevant for the Master).

You can check for further clues on one of the slave machines redis log files:

Linux command: *tail -f path-to-redis.log*

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility here is that the replication buffer is too low.

Thoroughly explained here: https://redis.com/blog/top-redis-headaches-for-devops-replication-buffer/

If you keep seeing in logs that replication is starting, and then from the master logs you see that connection is lost - this might be the issue (there is no specific log to direct you to that).

This happened to me on a big (>100GB) redis instance with high write load.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i commented the #masterauth otion on the redis configuration for the replicas.[replica config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyDgt.png)

Answer (score -1):

In my case, it was related to SELINUX, changing it to permissive mode resolved the issue.

Comment: It's better to fix the SELinux issue than to just disable it.

Answer (score -1):

**I fixed it the following**:

```
sudo -i
service redis-server stop
apt remove --purge redis-server
rm /var/lib/redis/dump.rdb
apt install redis-server
systemctl enable redis-server
service redis-server start

# i have not tried, but it is possible this is enough
service redis-server stop
rm /var/lib/redis/dump.rdb
service redis-server start
```

Comment: Cleaning up dump.rdb fixed my sync issues as well.  thanks for the suggestion.